# Can you please suggest self-hosted system with code snippets tagging?

Tags: tags, code-snippets, self-hosting

For Example: 
Sys-admin installed Oracle JDK on Ubuntu - it is about 5 lines bash commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
echo oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | sudo /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections
sudo apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

We would need to save those commands as bash code snippet and tag them as "Oracle JDK". Or for example PostgreSQL installation or any other stuff System team do repeatedly and need to find it quickly for quick revision

Please? any advise?

Comment: If you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CoderVault appears to be a good solution for teams doing all kinds of code snippets: https://github.com/codervault/codervault

If you want it directly in Bash, you would need to cook up some own form of snippet file, source it and sync it. For example, create a folder `.functions` and a file `~/.functions/shared` with the following content:

```
# Setup, do not change

alias sniplist="awk '/function/ {print $2;}' ~/.functions/shared"

function syncSnippets {
    P=$(pwd) && \
    cd ~/.functions && \
    git pull --rebase <HOST>/path/to/repo && \
    cd $P
    source ~/.functions/shared
}

# Add snippets below

function OracleJDK {
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java && \
    sudo apt-get update && \
    echo oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | sudo /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections && \
    sudo apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer && \
    sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
}
```

Add more functions as needed. The `&&` is for running all commands in sequence and aborting when one of them fails, `\` for being able to continue the same command on another line. This way, you're going to run a single chained command.

Create a Git repository (`git init`), add a server (`git remote add origin <HOST>/path/to/repo`), commit and push. Remember: you don't need a Git server to host a repository. You could just init it on the server and have it accessible by SSH, that's all you need.

All anyone else needs to do is clone this repo (`git clone <HOST>/path/to/repo ~/.functions`), source it in the shell config file (`source ~/.functions/shared`) and start another shell. Done.

Should you ever forget which snippets are available, just run `sniplist` and get a handy shortlist of functions.